# Node -v tells me I have a different version of node than I downloaded

Tags: node.js

I downloaded node version `8.11.3` from the node's download page on the website. The download was successful and when I run the `node -v` command in bash it tells me it is `8.1.3`. What is happening?

Comment: where are you running `node -v`, in the linux terminal, or the terminal inside some IDE. VS uses a different node version from the one you have installed on your system.

Comment: have you installed v8.1.3 before 8.11.3?

Comment: I'm running it in bash on the Visual Studio Code's terminal, but it macOS's terminal tells me the same thing. I previously had a 6.something version of node before updating.